# How do I check if certain pages have been indexed?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

What's the Google search to see how many pages are indexed within the search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you don't own the website**, [Google's `site:` operator](https://searchengineland.com/what-you-can-learn-from-googles-site-operator-14052) can give you some rough info. It's [not that accurate, though](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-site-command-accuracy-19094.html).

**If you do own the website**, use Google Search Console to check the [Index Coverage report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en). This should give you an accurate count of the number of pages that are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a certain page and not get a count of how many pages are indexed, you can search for a phrase from the page.

1. Choose a 6 to 10 word phrase from that page
2. Put it in quotes
3. Search for it in Google

For example if I search for a phrase you used:

> "Google search to see how many pages are indexed"

As of now, Google shows no results for that phrase, indicating that this page is not indexed.

---

If you have a list of pages from your site and you want to see how many of them are indexed, you can create a sitemap of them.

1. Create a sitemap containing only the URLs you want to know about.
2. Add the sitemap to Google search console.
3. Wait until Google reports stats for that sitemap.  It is usually within a week, but I've seen reports recently of it taking months in some cases.
4. Google will tell you how many of the pages in the sitemap are indexed and give you an index coverage report for just the pages in the sitemap.